# Timing Issue trying to AssumeRole into AWS Account from master account using boto3 on AWS

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-sts, assume-role

I have a Python script that creates a new AWS account from the master account. Then it uses assume_role to access the newly created account. I have a custom waiter to check that the account has created. However, not sure if due to a timing issue or something else, sometimes the assume_role shows AccessDenied. Putting in a time.sleep(x) seems to help. I was wondering if there was a better way to do this (Is it possible to make a custom waiter for assume_role?).

```
def assume_role(assumed_session, account_id, account_alias):
    client = assumed_session.client('sts')
    assumed_role_object = client.assume_role(
        RoleArn = "arn:aws:iam::%s:role/MyCustomRole2" % account_id,
        RoleSessionName = account_alias
    )
    time.sleep(x)
    credentials = assumed_role_object['Credentials']
    return credentials
```

The error I get occasionally is

```
('An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/MyCustomRole1/my-org is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::YYYYYYYYYYYY:role/MyCustomRole2',)
```

Comment: So, if you simply wait, then it works? I'm not aware of any waiter that understands IAM propagation delays (assuming that's the root cause here) but you can see what waiters are available at `boto3.client('iam').waiter_names`.

Comment: Yes, it works when I add a wait. I tried client.waiter_names, but it was an empty list.

Comment: IAM waiters for me are: `['instance_profile_exists', 'policy_exists', 'role_exists', 'user_exists']`

Comment: I was using boto3.client('sts').waiter_names

Comment: There's a sample custom waiter [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-demo_tools-custom_waiter.py.html).